# 2-Dimensional array in memory in ANSI C

Tags: c, arrays

I've read many people here and in other websites saying that if a declare something like this:

```
double a[5][2];
```

it will be allocated in memory like a contiguous block  like:

```
a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | ....etc
```

But is this always a rule?
I would like to create a function to multiply matrices of variable sizes but in pure C I won't be able to pass matrices by parameters without knowing at least one dimension. So I've made this:

```
void MatMult(double* m1, double* m2, double* res, int h, int w, int l)
{
  int i, j, k;
  for (i = 0; i < h; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < w; j++)
    {
        double p_res = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < l; k++)
        {
            p_res += (*(m1+i*l+k))*(*(m2+k*w+j));
        }
        *(res+i*w+j)=p_res;
    }
  }
}
```

with call:

```
 double m1[2][3], m2[3][1], m3[2][1];
 ...
 MatMult(&(m1[0][0]),&(m2[0][0]),&(m3[0][0]),2,1,3);
```

And it worked. But will this always work or there are exceptions that I should be aware of like memory aligment or something like this?

Comment: What you're doing is treating the Matrix like a 1-D array, and working out offsets into it. This is fine and I think it would be even simpler to store your matrices as 1-D arrays in the first place.

Comment: You can use array syntax, it might make things clearer... `p_res += m1[I*l+k] * m2[k*w+j];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will always work. Arrays declared like you did ara guaranteed to be "contiguous" which means that their items will be tightly packed up. So, if you declare `double[55]` you know that always the `[50]`-th element will come right after `[49]`-th element with no **perceivable** gaps.

<strike>I think, but I'm not perfectly sure, that for some very uncommon data types (like including unbalanced bitfields, etc), the "alignment" can still kick in and offset something. I'm not sure. But **even if**</strike> (see Jens comment) If the compiler adds some alignment offsets, it will do so either inside a single data element, or at the boudary between elements, and in both cases the compiler will know about it. So, it should apply all required corrections at every `[], ->, .` operation, as long as it still has all the required type information (array-of-doubles). If you erase the type information and start accessing the array by "untyped" (or wrong-typed) pointers, for example:

```
double array[50];
char* p = (char*)array;
int size = sizeof(double);
for(i=0;i<50;++i)
    .. *(double*)(p+size) ..
```

then of course the compiler will not have the type information and will be unable to apply proper alignment offsets. But if you do things as above, you probably know the risks already.

Next thing is, that there is no such thing as two-dimensional array. Neither in C nor in C++.

Array defined as `double[5][2]` is an array(5) of array(2) of double. CMIIW, I could swap them. Anyways, the point is that 'double' is a datatype and is an element of an higher-level 1D-array. Then, `double[2]` is a datatype and an element of an higher-level 1D-array, and so on.

Now, remember the 'sequential+contiguous' layout of arrays:

```
double            ->  DD
double[2]         -> [DD | DD]
double[5][2]      -> [ {DD:DD} | {DD:DD} | {DD:DD} | {DD:DD} | {DD:DD} ]
```

Since array has to be sequential and contiguous, the double[2] must layout its element as above - obvious.

However, since double[5][2] is an array, and its an array of [5] and since its elements are double[2] - it must layout its elements just in the same way. First whole element first, then second whole element, and so on.

Just like double[2] can't "split" its doubles into scattered 1-byte chunks, the double[5][2] can't split its array[2].

Comment: The `sizeof` operator is guaranteed to give the size that an item has when inside an array. Remember that allocating even one element in C is always equivalent to allocating an array with one element. Once you have taken the address of a variable, something like `&A`, you only know that this starts an array of the base type with at least one element.

Comment: @JensGustedt: yes I understand that, but actually, I fail to see what issue in my port you are referring to. If you mean the first code example, I've already tried to be clear that's hackings and not fully safe. Or, if you mean passing the array by its first element, it's still the same base array type. IIRC, the alignment rules will be the same, regardless of whether it's a `double[5]`, `double [2][5][3]` or `double`. Or do I remember it wrong? Could happen. My few years in C# could have done any damage ;)

Comment: no, no, I was just referring to your uncertainty whether alignment can kick in somewhere: it can't.

Comment: @cmaster: Thank you very much. I've erased the "BTW" section. It seems I'm getting rusty. Let me only ask - are you sure that C (not C++) also has this rule? I know that in C++ that would not be possible, but I was really sure it's convertible to plain d* in C.

Answer (score 3):

To pass 2D arrays to functions you'd have to change your interface

```
void MatMult(size_t h, size_t w, size_t l. double m1[h][w], double m2[w][l], double res[h][l]);
```

or similar:

- have the sizes first
- then use them to declare the dimensions

Also, I have used `size_t`, here, since this is the correct type for all index calculations.

This should work for all compilers that implement C99. (Basically all do but Microsoft.)

Comment: Yes, that was my fear. I read this very similar to what you've said here: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html but I'm working with PIC microcontrollers with XC16 compiler which follows C89 standards, so it should not work, unfortunately. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Too bad that they still don't support this.

Comment: Ah, and please don't call it ANSI C. The current ANSI norm for C is C11.

Answer (score -4):

By using `double a[5][2]`, you are creating two dimensional array in stack which will always be a contiguous block of memory. On the other hand, if you try to create 2-D array on heap (i.e. using malloc), it is not guaranteed that you will get contiguous block of memory hence you might not be able traverse your allocated memory in a linear way.

Comment: -1, why would a dynamic allocation not get a contigouous block?

Comment: while creating a full 2-D array using malloc, it is not guaranteed that two back to back calls of malloc would give you a contiguous block memory. In linux at least...

Comment: You'd only need one call. `malloc(sizeof(double[x][y]))` should do the trick.

Comment: `malloc` returns a pointer to a contiguous block of memory... There's no reason why a stack allocated 2D array would be continuous but a `malloc`ed 2D array wouldn't be.

Comment: @JewelThief: if you had in mind a `double**` approach with a malloc(X) followed by a loop that malloc(Y) X times, then you understood something very wrong. It's not a 2-D array at all. It just can be indexed twice. Only what JensGustedt shown could eventually count as dynamic 2D array.

Comment: @JensGustedt; He is right. In case of multi-dimentional array using `malloc` would not give the contiguous memory blocks.

Comment: @haccks, what? We are **not** talking about `double**` pseudo-multidimenisional arrays.

Comment: @JensGustedt; He states that: *On the other hand, if you try to create 2-D array on heap (i.e. using malloc), it is not guaranteed that you will get contiguous block of memory*.